# How To Reset Button Back To Original State After Clicking On It Again?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, accordion

I have an accordion where the panels are pseudo buttons that expand the accordion content once the "buttons" are clicked and the currently open accordion panel closes once I click on another one. The problem I have is that if I click on the panel once to open the accordion and click on it again to close it, it stays focused (the orange border remains) and I cannot figure out how to bring the button back to the state it was in before I clicked it? In the same way it is reset when I click on another panel?

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {

    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      let active = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion-div .accordion.active");
      for (let j = 0; j < active.length; j++) {
        active[j].classList.remove("active");
        active[j].nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null;
      }
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #00000042;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #00000042;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #00000042;
  border: 1px solid #fc8e2d;
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: #00000042;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion-div">
  <button class="accordion"><span class="faq__question-heading">Title1</span></button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p style="padding:18px 0;">description1</p>
  </div>

  <button class="accordion"><span class="faq__question-heading">Title2</span></button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p style="padding:18px 0;">description2</p>
  </div>

  <button class="accordion"><span class="faq__question-heading">Title3</span></button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p style="padding:18px 0;">description3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me how I should change my code?

I tried changing the JavaScript by using this

```
for (var j = 0; j < acc.length; j++) {
    acc[j].nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null;
}
```

but it messes up the entire JS and it stops working.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      let active = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion-div .accordion.active");
      for(let j = 0; j < active.length; j++){
        active[j].classList.remove("active");
        active[j].nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null;
      }
      // this.classList.toggle("active"); // move this down, outside of
      // both if and else, since it should apply in any case
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";

    }
    
    this.classList.toggle("active"); // just add this
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #00000042;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  margin-top:20px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #00000042;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
  background-color: #00000042;
  border: 1px solid #fc8e2d;
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: #00000042;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion-div">
  <button class="accordion"><span class="faq__question-heading">Title1</span></button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p style="padding:18px 0;">description1</p>
  </div>

  <button class="accordion"><span class="faq__question-heading">Title2</span></button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p style="padding:18px 0;">description2</p>
  </div>

  <button class="accordion"><span class="faq__question-heading">Title3</span></button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p style="padding:18px 0;">description3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The reason for the change - toggling of the `active` class should happen regardless of whether the clicked element had that class or not.

Also, as an aside - instead of having a click event handler for every panel (addEventListener within a loop), consider using delegation - attach the event handler on the parent element, and check if the receiver of the click was your panel.

For example:

```js
var acc = document.querySelector(".accordion-div");

acc.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  if(!target.classList.contains("accordion")) {
    return false;
  }
  
  var panel = target.nextElementSibling;
  if (panel.style.maxHeight){
    panel.style.maxHeight = null;
  } else {
    let active = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion-div .accordion.active");
    for(let j = 0; j < active.length; j++){
      active[j].classList.remove("active");
      active[j].nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null;
    }
    panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
  }
  target.classList.toggle("active");
});
```

```css
.accordion {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #00000042;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  margin-top:20px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #00000042;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
  background-color: #00000042;
  border: 1px solid #fc8e2d;
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: #00000042;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion-div">
  <button class="accordion"><span class="faq__question-heading">Title1</span></button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p style="padding:18px 0;">description1</p>
  </div>

  <button class="accordion"><span class="faq__question-heading">Title2</span></button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p style="padding:18px 0;">description2</p>
  </div>

  <button class="accordion"><span class="faq__question-heading">Title3</span></button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p style="padding:18px 0;">description3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, works perfectly. I'll play around with it some more but thank you!